# carriage return in strwrap in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify my input text in order to get strwrap to start a new line at a given place *without* an extra line in between (a paragraph break).

My desired output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus malesuada ante eget lacus aliquam aliquet. Morbi a
nulla in tortor rutrum pulvinar.

Duis auctor condimentum magna ac commodo. Phasellus quis
elementum purus, at ornare magna. Quisque sit amet vehicula
risus. Suspendisse et  et scelerisque velit:
item #1
item #2
item #3
```

I can use \n to get the paragraph break, which works fine, but how do I get a new line without the paragraph break, as in the list of items at the bottom? When I use \r...

```
txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus malesuada ante eget lacus aliquam aliquet. Morbi a nulla 
in tortor rutrum pulvinar. 
\n
Duis auctor condimentum magna ac commodo. Phasellus quis elementum purus, 
at ornare magna. Quisque sit amet vehicula risus. Suspendisse et 
scelerisque velit:
\r
item #1 
item #2
item #3"
writeLines(strwrap(txt, width=60))
```

... I get an unexpected result: a line break but with an extra space indent and some juxtaposition and deletion of text:

```
#Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
#Vivamus malesuada ante eget lacus aliquam aliquet. Morbi a
#nulla in tortor rutrum pulvinar.
#
#Duis auctor condimentum magna ac commodo. Phasellus quis
#elementum purus, at ornare magna. Quisque sit amet vehicula
# item #1 item #2se et scelerisque velit: 
#item #3
```

What do I need to replace /r with in order to get a single line break, like between "velit:" and "item #1" in the desired output above? I've read the strwrap documentation and worked through its example, but haven't found the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to replace \r with something that will produce a line break, without the empty line. \n results in the extra empty line.

Comment: When I use \n in the input to strwrap, it results in a paragraph break. What do I need to type in the input in order to get a line break? I want to leave some instances of /n in the code when a paragraph break is needed.

Comment: @lost, if you just want to print the text with line breaks, use `cat(txt)`, or do you want save the string as well ?

Comment: I just want to modify the input to the strwrap function in order to produce a line break in the output. I'm saving the text to a .txt document.

Comment: I think it is not possible as there are only paragraphs and tokens. See [the source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/15420649/). You need to roll out your own function.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the off-change that someone else finds this question in the future, I'll share the solution I used here. As Wiktor points out above, strwrap does not have this functionality. What I ended up doing was simply a workaround that edits the text after it goes through strwrap.

I add an arbitrary character sequence to the beginning of each line in the input which I want to start with a carriage return. Below I use "/r" for this. I send the input through strwrap, add two empty lines to the end, and then parse each line of the output, deleting "/r" and removing the empty preceding line (paragraph break). Here's the code:

```
txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus malesuada ante eget lacus aliquam aliquet. Morbi a nulla 
in tortor rutrum pulvinar. 
\n
Duis auctor condimentum magna ac commodo. Phasellus quis elementum purus, 
at ornare magna. Quisque sit amet vehicula risus. Suspendisse et 
scelerisque velit:
\n\r item #1 
\n\r item #2
\n\r item #3"

sink("output.txt")
lines <- append(strwrap(txt, width=100), c("",""), after = length(lines))
invisible(lapply(seq_along(lines), function(index) {
  if (index != 1) { #skip first line
    if (!grepl("\r ", lines[index])) { 
       writeLines(gsub("\r ", "", lines[index-1]))
    }
  }
}))
sink()
```

This produces a .txt file with the output text formatted as desired, where the list of items at the bottom is separated by carriage returns/newlines but paragraph breaks marked in the input with just "/n" are treated normally.